# Am I performing my order of operations incorrectly in Java?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I'm having a bit of trouble with this question.

I'm unsure where % (mod) sits on the BEDMAS order of operations.

```
37 % 20 % 3 * 4 = ?
```

My mental arithmetic answer is 5 but I must be doing something wrong. Where does % mod sit within BEDMAS?

Comment: Why don't you just run the code and see for yourself what is the order of operations here?

Comment: What do you mean with "My answer is 5"? Is that 'your' answer if you manually calculate, or is that the output of your Java code (which it shouldn't, it should be 8, so then we'd like to see a [mre]).

Comment: @Amongalen 

I'm not interested in the output but moreso the order of operations

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my mental arithmetic answer is (incorrectly) 5. i should have clarified

Comment: @Tarapuka considering how simple this equation is, you could easily deduce an asnwer to your question. How many possible outcomes can you think of? 2? 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modulu (`%`) operator has the same precedence as the division (`/`) operator, so:

37 % 20 is 17
17 % 3 is 2
2 * 4 is 8

[IDEOne output](https://ideone.com/DT7tkv)

Comment: A a reference: [Java Language Spec chapter 15.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17): The operators `*`, `/`, and `%` are called the multiplicative operators ... they  have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

Answer (score 4):

BEDMAS is misleading as it suggests Division before Multiplication.
It is more something for primary school.

It should be

1. multiplicative operations: * / %
2. additive (binary) operations: + -

Brackets, unary (-), bits and logic operations not entirely covered by BEDMAS too.

```
    (((37 % 20) % 3) * 4) = 8
```

And **not** Multiplication after Modulo:

```
    ((37 % 20) % (3 * 4)) = 5  ***
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and java outputs the exactly right result. 37 % 20 = 17, 17 % 3 = 2, 2 * 4 = 8. But refer to [MathExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849713/where-does-modulus-take-place) for your BEDMAS question